# Can't find the thumbnail element in RSS feed

Tags: ios, uitableview, thumbnails, nsxmlparser, rss-reader

I'm doing a test where I'm building a news feed iOS app, using rss feeds like this one: http://www.20minutos.es/iphoneapp/feeds/home/

I'm almost done, but I can't find the link to the thumbnail. I'm doing the parsing like this and I can find some  enclosure, enclosure2x, thumbnail, thumbnail2x, but they're all empty strings:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        image = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        image2x = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        comments = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
        [item setObject:image2x forKey:@"image2x"];
        [item setObject:comments forKey:@"comments"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"veinteminutos:numComments"]) {
        [comments appendString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];
    }
    //NSLog(@"string: %@ \nelement: %@ \n\n\n", string, element);

}
```

It's my first time parsing rss feeds, so I don't really know what to look for in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse out the `media:thumbnail` and `media:thumbnail2x` nodes in the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` delegate method and extract the thumbnail URLs from the `attributeDict` dictionary:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        image = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        image2x = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        comments = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {
        image = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail2x"]) {
        image2x = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
}
```

You can do the same for the enclosures, should you need them.